# AngularJS: Routeprovider is not firing routeChangeStart?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, routes

I am trying to get a `routeProvider` running in an AngularJS app. This seems quite straightforward, but i seem to be missing something - at least my links are not working yet.

I tried to debug my code with firebug, but the `routeChangeStart` event which i wanted to observe with the following code is not firing.

```
app.run(['$rootScope',
    function($rootScope) {
       $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
       var currentPath = current.originalPath;
       var nextPath = next.originalPath;

       console.log('current: %s; next: %s', currentPath, nextPath);
      });
     }
    ]);
```

**Setup:**

My `index.html` contains some links pointing to `#/page` and a line `<div ng-view></div>` which should load the content of page.html when a link is clicked.

The `app.js` file which contains my routeprovider is called correctly in my `index.html` (Firebug runs through it on pageload).

My routeProvider is setup like this:

```
angular.module('MyModule', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
  .when("/page", {templateUrl: "partials/page.html", controller: "TestCtrl"})
  .when(...);
```

Is there anything i forgot to get the routeProvider running? I tried to stick as close as possible to the example at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route and don't really know how i can debug this when there is nothing running that i could debug.

Comment: are ajax requests being made for the templates? What URL are you using...are you including a hash?

Comment: no ajax requests yet, it is all running at a local server for now which should just redirect to static .html ressources. The URL which is called by the links is `http://localhost:8080/Mainpage/#/page`

Comment: `templateUrl` will cause ajax request, unless you are putting templates in script tags or templateCache. Is `page.html` an actual file still?

Comment: yes, i have a file named page.html with some content